# How can i write a number values in powers of 10?

Tags: matlab

How can I write a number/Integer value to power of 10, e.g. 1000 as 10^3? I am writing code whose output is a string of very large numbers. My output in longEng format is:

```
4.40710646596169e+018
16.9749211806197e+186
142.220634811050e+078
508.723835280617e+204
1.15401317731033e-177
129.994388899690e+168
14.3008811642810e+153
1.25899227268954e+165
24.1450064703939e+150
627.108997290435e+144
2.03728822649372e+177
339.903986115177e-066
150.360900017430e+183
5.39003779219462e+135
183.893417489826e+198
648.544709490386e+045
19.7574461055182e+198
3.91455750674308e+102
6.41548629454028e-114
70.4943280639616e+096
19.7574461055182e+198
3.11450571506133e-009
249.857950606210e+093
4.64921904682151e+180
750.343029004712e+147
```

I want these results to be in a format of power of 10, so that I can easily do arithmetic operations for my next function.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It would be helpful if you could share your expected output for this code. How should the output differ from what you're seeing right now?

Comment: Just stating the obvious, but these ***are*** powers of 10, so what do you want to do differently? As far as performing arithmetic operations, doesn't care what format the numbers are printed in when doing calculations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can write `format shortE`  and see you output like this:

```
  4.4071e+18
  1.6975e+187
  1.4222e+80
  5.0872e+206
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to print the data in scientific format, the Matlab itself can do this for you. 
If you can to obtain the scientific notation form as

```
a * 10^b,
```

i.e., obtain the coefficient a and the exponent b, you can first obtain the b as:

```
b = floor(log10(abs(x)));
```

then the a as:

```
a = x * 10^(-b);
```

Comment: Thanks, its working but still the output has the same result instead of above scientific format. Can you tell me how can i see the output in above format.

Comment: you have obtain the coefficient a and the exponent b, then you can use them in your next function. What you see is just how to print them.

Answer (score 0):

from my understanding you wish to take your number e.g. 4.40710646596169e+018 and split it up into:

4.40710646596169 and 018 once you have them separated you you can perform operations as you wish.

You can even join them back to look like: 4.40710646596169^018 if you so desire (although to look like that they would be strings and therefore mathematical operations on the number would be NAN).

Since e represents to the power 10 and is present in all numbers you listed this is a simple process with many solutions, here is one.

```
% format long is very important otherwise it will appear to you that you have
%lost precision. MATLAB hides precision from view to save screen space and to
%produce less confusing results to the viewer. (the precision is still there but 
%with format long you will be able to see it.
    format long

    x = 4.40710646596169e+018;

%convert your number into a string, this will allow you to split the number based
%on the always present e+ 'delimiter' (not really a delimiter but looks like one')
    s = num2str(x);

%use strsplit to perform the split in the required place. it will output a 1x2 
%cell
    D = strsplit(s, {'e+'});

%extract each cell to a separate variable. in fact D{1} can be directly used for 
%the input of the next function. 
    D11 = D{1};
    D22 = D{2};

%convert the separated strings back into numbers with double precision (keep
%maintin value accuracy)
    D1 = str2double(D11)
    D2 = str2double(D22)
```

in order to do this operation on an entire column vector it is simply a matter of using a for loop to iterate through all the numbers you have.